# X locks up with Konqueror on comics.com

Tags: x-windows, fedora-11, konqueror

If I browse to [comics.com](http://comics.com/rose_is_rose) using Konqueror under KDE on Fedora 11, X will, after a delay, lock up.  The mouse will move, but no keyboard input is recognized, and the screen does not react to the mouse passing over objects on screen.  I am able to ssh into the machine and issue `shutdown -r now` and have that work.

The machine is a Dell XPS M1330 with Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c), and Fedora 11 is fully updated.

Visiting the same site in Firefox does not cause a lockup.

I am booting with `nomodeset` since it won't boot into X otherwise.
I tried the other two accel options: `EXA` (still locks up) and `XAA` (X won't start).

Any suggestions on how I can debug this?

[bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=551464)

Comment: Is it just that site?

Comment: No, but that site will trigger the problem reliably.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Konqueror across multiple versions of multiple distributions. I don't know of any specific fix, nor do I know if it's been corrected in F12. I would suggest grabbing a F12 KDE Live CD and testing that.